# discrete maths-combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**Hi..i have a doubt in permutation and combination..

i already know permutation is an a method of arrangement of a set of n objects in a given order that means in permutation order of objects  is important .

combination is a method of total ways of doing a particular task ..here order of objects in the selection does not matter.

But if  a question is given as  follows how to identify whether this question is of permutation or combination.

How many integers between 100 and 999 consist of distinct even digits.

I have done as follows
The total no of even digits are(0,2,4,6,8)=5 and a number is identified as even by its last digit.

As first digit can not be 0 so it  can take any of the 9 digits(1-10)
Second digit can take 8
3rd digit can take 5
so my answer came out to be 9*8*5.

is it correct**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all if question is specifying "*distinct even **digits***", it means you can use only digits out of the set $\{0,2,4,6,8\}$.

Moving forward, To identify if the question is of permutation or combination is simple. What you said is right, if the order of objects of selection matters, it's permutation else it's combination. For example here, if you select the first integer out of $\{0,2,4,6,8\}$, you are not allowed to select it again.

Thus, the total number of such numbers is $4\times4\times3 = 48$.

Comment: but in my book  ans is given as 4*5*5

Comment: Yes, because the question is NOT asking about even numbers, it asks you for numbers with **even digits**

Comment: but in my book ans is given as 4*5*5

Comment: It's probably wrong then. Because For first (hundredth's place you can have 4 possibilities, then for tens place you are left with 4 again (because you can use zero here), the ones place is left with only 3 integers. Thus the number = 4*4*3=48

Comment: 4*5*5 would be the answer if the digits did not need to be distinct.

Comment: If the digits have to be different, then $4*4*3$. If they don't have to be different, then $4*5*5$

Comment: and how to prove (m+n)!>=m!+n!..i had tried it bstion from but not able to solve..it is also question from permutation

Comment: @AbhinandanDubey You can edit posts (questions and answers) rather than tag wikis.

Comment: @Integrator : I couldn't get you by that. Why are you saying that ?

Comment: @AbhinandanDubey Please take a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/198578/abhinandan-dubey?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

Comment: @AbhinandanDubey If you're interested in making contributions to MathSE, You're most welcome! I'd recommend you to contribute by editing questions or answers. **Not** tag wikis

Comment: @Integrator : I read an article in the help section where i found the guidelines for body of tag wikis. There it was written that, MathSE wants to have body for all tag wikis. And I found most of the tag wikis did not have bodies. So i thought to add them according to the guidelines. Seems strange that you rejected most of the contributions.

Comment: @AbhinandanDubey I've only reviewed one of those $3$ edits and I've approved it. But I'll recommend not to edit tag wikis until you get familiar with Math SE! Good Luck! have Fun!